# Can't apply any JS modification on custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar, configure

I'm trying to configure the custom scrollbar I set up on my test forums; the scrollbar itself works, but not the way I'd like to. So i'm trying to configure it, but it simply doesn't work.

I used this : http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Example of my JS code :

```
$("#bodyID").mCustomScrollbar({
    mouseWheel: { 
        enable: boolean 
    } 
});
```

Concerned forums : http://twenty-two.forumactif.org/

### **UPDATE**

Actually, holding the mouse wheel to navigate faster isn't working, and i'm trying to solve this issue. I tried to change "boolean" to either false or true, but nothing changed.

Comment: "The scrollbar itself works, but not the way I'd like it to" - Well, how do you want it to work? There appears to be a heap of configurable options you pass into a configuration object as you have pasted above.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I'm guessing 'boolean' should be either `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

The configuration snippet you have provided is matching the one in the website, so there should be no issues with the syntax, except that you need to replace the `boolean` keyword with an actual value - either true or false.

Would that not be the case, then the issue is related to your selector or it is not inside the context shown to us - therefore you would need to provide more information about this issue.